# Android ADT plugin error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I installed the Android SDK. When I try to import the ADT plugin I get this error:

```
"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 10.0.0.v201102162101-104271) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found"
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://tewson.com/content/orgeclipsegef-000-required-installing-android-development-tools-eclipse-351). It looks exactly like your issue.

Comment: i tried updating it to 3.6 still didnt work, my error message says "org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0" from where do i get this, the version r started from 1 but here y its showing zero

Comment: Did you go through the 6 steps at the top of the link I posted?

Answer (score -1):

Is this the first time running the application? If know you may need to uninstall the app from the emulator or device. I ran into this issue before I just made sure the the old app was no longer on the device I was using.

Also if that doesn't work provde and little bit more info so we can help. Perhaps open up the DDMS perspective and seletct the emulator you are using. DDMS is a very helpful tool to determine what is going on.

Comment: LLL is not trying to install an APK on an AVD